# how to send the logs from spring boot application to aws cloudwatch logs through ec2 session manager?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-session-manager

i have installed the cloudwatch agent and have given the right iam permissons to the role but the spring boot logs are not coming just ec2 logs are coming, what should i do to get the spring boot logs to cloudwatch

i have done these steps in session manager

step1
sudo yum install awslogs

step2
cd /etc/awslogs

step3
ls

step4
sudo cat awscli.conf

step5

sudo cat awslogs.conf

but the spring boot logs are not coming and just some ec2 logs are coming, what did i do wrong or do we need to add something in spring boot application other then the access key, secret key and region?

Comment: According to my knowledge, you need to install the Unified CloudWatch Agent on the EC2 instance and when you configure it, it will ask you which files you want to *monitor* and just point it to the Springboot log file.

Comment: i have installed it but what code do we need to write in spring boot applications file

Comment: https://reflectoring.io/struct-log-with-cloudwatch-tutorial/

Comment: i tried this, but not clear enough, and i am using the logback and they are using the log4j maybe